# Mac OS X LDAP query via dscl yields different results for same user with same datasource

Tags: osx, ldap

Where is the `NFSHomeDirectory` attribute stored for a Mac user who authenticates via LDAP?  It doesn't seem to be in the LDAP database on the backend so I assume Open Directory is involved.

I have 2 servers, one is 10.5.8 and one is 10.7.  Each is an Open Directory Master.  We also have Sun LDAP which is the authoritative LDAP for our entire environment.

When I do `dscl /LDAPv3/our.ldap.server read /Users/ouruser` I get a different result for the `NFSHomeDirectory` attribute on the two servers, but I'm querying the same LDAP server in both instances.

How could this be?  What am I not understanding?

I assume the attributes are all stored in LDAP since that is what I'm querying.  Could it be caching?

#### Some history

The newer server was created by cloning the old one with Carbon Copy Cloner and then updating it.  Pinging the LDAP server results in the same IP on both machines.

Comment: These tips might help you: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1431816&seqNum=2

Comment: Thanks but Active Directory is not part of this equation.  I would really like to know where the NFSHomeDirectory attribute is stored for a Mac user.

Comment: The tips for debugging I thought might be relevant. AD is just a glorified LDAP server.

Comment: That's true, I am thinking that this attribute is coming from the OD side of things, since I assume if it was stored in LDAP, that I would get the same answer from any client when pointing to this LDAP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out with some help from forums. It is mapping certain attributes from a local Open Directory database to the Sun LDAP server, so if you query LDAP via dscl on the local server, some of the attributes between the two server's local OD databases differed, thus different results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that versed in OSX, but in Linux there is `nscd`, which does cache values. Can you `strace` things on OSX? Tracing the `dscl` command will likely turn up what's getting reused from a cache if that's indeed the issue.

The caching by `nscd` is discussed here in this Debian wiki article: [LDAP NSS](http://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/NSS). If you have a service such as `nscd` running you could try disabling it.

Comment: I was considering tracing it using the Mac utility fs_usage which is a fork of Solaris' dtrace, however I would have to make the distinction between tracing network or filesys calls.  I guess I can try filesys and see if a cache or local DB gets referenced.

Comment: I figured it out with some help from forums.  It is mapping certain attributes from a local Open Directory database to the Sun LDAP server, so if you query LDAP via dscl on the local server, some of the attributes between the two server's local OD databases differed, thus different results.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - ahh. Makes sense. Write it up and mark it as your accepted answer, might save someone else the trouble in the future.